# Как скрыть AppBarLayout программно в android?

Tags: java, android

**Есть AppBar выглядит вот так:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь скрыть AppBarLayout программно, но у меня не получается, он оставляет за собой белый или черный фон в зависимости от режима (тёмный режим или обычный):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал много раз по-разному, но у меня не получается, помогите разобраться.

**Вот как пытаюсь скрыть:**

1. Первый метод

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

2. Второй метод

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

3. Третий метод

```
appBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Основная разметка:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_framelayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content_relativelayout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" >
            
            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/teal"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/url_bar_background_white"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/app_bar_back"
                            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                            android:src="@drawable/back"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:onClick="onClick"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/back" />
                       
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

                <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                        <com.exemple.views.NoSwipeViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/webviewpager"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/bookmarks_drawer"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Странно что когда прямо в разметке присвоишь android:visibility="gone" то убирается нормально, но программно не хочет!

Comment: попробуйте через findViewById(R.id. appbar_layout) скрывать, именно этот элемент

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но решения заключалось в том что после скрытия, нужно было убрать padding top  которые стоял (программно), и за этого в разметка показывала пустая поля